# getStylesheet depending if class exists

Tags: javascript, css, function, if-statement

I need to add a css stylesheet if a certain css class exists in a page.

i.e. editing the following JS:

```
<script>
<!--
function getStylesheet() {
      var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
      if (0 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 5) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='night.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (5 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 11) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='morning.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (11 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 16) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='day.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
      if (16 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 22) {
       document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='evening.css' type='text/css'>");
      }
}

getStylesheet();
-->
</script>
```

Rather than above times, I need to add a css file if a certian class is present in a page - i.e.

if class="company" - use company.css

if class="contact" - use contact.css

if class="enterprise" - use enterprise.css

if class="media" - use media.css

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, you can determine if a class is present on the page by using the following:

```
if ($('.class').length){
    // code
}
```

Substituting in `.class` for whatever class you're attempting to see if present.

So:

```
if ($('.company').length){
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='company.css' type='text/css'>");
}
if ($('.contact').length){
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='contact.css' type='text/css'>");
}
etc...
```

Comment: Superb... just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, which I recommend anyway:

```
var myTypes = ['company', 'contact', 'enterprise', 'media'];
for (i in myTypes) {
    if ($('.' + myTypes[i]).length) {
        loadMyCSS(myTypes[i])
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this. There's no benefit to it. Just keep it all in one stylesheet and change the styles on the page based on a class on `<body>` or `<html>`. Here's a quick example.

```
<body class="page-company">
```

then do

```
.page-company h1 { }
```

and so on.